# How to change header "from" sending mail

Tags: php, email, header

I use this method to send a mail on my website :

```
$message="Hello";
$headers='From: info@hosting.com'."\r\n".'Reply-To: info@hosting.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
mail("destination@mail.com", "Title", $message, $headers);
```

but when I receive it, the field `From` is written as `info`.

How can I change it? Such as `My Website Hosting`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this header instead: `From: "My Website Hosting" <info@hosting.com>`